# Task Trigger fired for one record after email send

Tags: trigger, email, batch, governorlimits

I just learned in a very painful way that when sending SingleMessage emails tagged to be saved as activity the task trigger is called for each single message at once not in bulk. 
I'm sending from batch and even though I'm hitting query limits
Stupid question but is there a setting to overcome it? The only thing I can think of is changing the batch size.

Comment: please use [edit] and show the code in the batch `execute()` where you send the emails

Comment: a workaround would be to delegate the work to a custom object EmailProxy__c that in turn uses a WFR or PB to send the email + create a Task.  I would expect this to be bulkified

Answer (score 0):

Ah well I can [vote](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CTXwQAO) and wait 10 years